# Center text horizontally and vertically using bootstrap in HTML div

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to complete this page for freecodecamp and I'm stuck on a few details.

[Here's my code](https://codepen.io/nitreg/pen/wdWPEb)

I'm trying to get the "Martin Luther King Jr civil rights hero and icon" title centered vertically in the div. I'm also trying to center horizontally with the h3 tag "Timeline of Martin Luther King Jr.'s Life".

I've tried text-align:center; and the text-center bootstrap class. Neither seemed to work. I've also tried adding !important to see if maybe the bootstrap class was overriding it somehow. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<h1 class="display-2 text-center">Martin Luther King Jr</h1>
    <h3 class="text-center text-muted font-italic">civil rights hero and icon</h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using flex box - you may want to leverage `align-items` and `justify-content` properties.

Here's the slightly updated markup and css

HTML

```
<div class="col centered-content" style="border-style:solid;border-color:grey;border-radius:20px;background-color:white!important;background-color: white;">
    <div class="centered-content__inner">
        <h1 class="display-2 text-center" style="">Martin Luther King Jr</h1>
        <h3 class="text-center text-muted font-italic">civil rights hero and icon</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.centered-content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.centered-content__inner {
    background: none;
}
```

More on content centering with flex box [here](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks! that worked for me. i didn't realized centering was such an issue with css so appreciate the solution!

Comment: Algoods happy to help. Remember that flex box used to have a different syntax which is supported by older browser versions, refer to this link to get a feel for overall flexbox adoption by major browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Make the div with class `row` display as a table and the two children as table-cell. Then you can apply a vertical align middle

```
.row{
  display:table
}
.row .col,.row .col-5{
  display:table-cell;
}
.centered div:first-child{
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

[click here for demo](https://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/aWZGJY)